# Concatenating Values into a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this

```
ID   Qusetion_NO  answer
001      1           a
001      2           b
001      4           c
002      1           d
002      2           e
002      3           f
002      4           g
```

I need to take column B and C turn it into a row.
It would ideally end up like :

```
ID     1    2    3   4
001    a    b        c
002    d    e    f   g
```

How do I get this table using MS-SQL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there always a maximum of 4 answers or is the number dynamic?

Comment: always 4 answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this.

```
select ID
    , max(case when Question_NO = 1 then answer end) as [1]
    , max(case when Question_NO = 2 then answer end) as [2]
    , max(case when Question_NO = 3 then answer end) as [3]
    , max(case when Question_NO = 4 then answer end) as [4]
FROM YourTable
group by ID
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PIVOT` for make it.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID VARCHAR(3),   Qusetion_NO  INT, answer VARCHAR(3))

INSERT @T
VALUES
('001',1,'a'),
('001',2,'b'),
('001',4,'c'),
('002',1,'d'),
('002',2,'e'),
('002',3,'f'),
('002',4,'g')

SELECT * FROM  
    (SELECT * FROM @T) SRC 
        PIVOT(MAX(answer) 
            FOR Qusetion_NO IN( [1], [2], [3], [4] ) ) PVT
```

Result:

```
ID   1    2    3    4
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
001  a    b    NULL c
002  d    e    f    g
```

Comment: You don't need to use the subquery here.

Comment: Maybe subquery not necessary for this query but I prefer to use this convention. It's my way

Comment: OK. To me it just makes the code more complicated with no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try :

```
    SELECT ID,
       ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MAX(CASE
                                             WHEN Qusetion_NO = 1
                                             THEN answer
                                         END)), '') AS [1],
       ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MAX(CASE
                                             WHEN Qusetion_NO = 2
                                             THEN answer
                                         END)), '') AS [2],
       ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MAX(CASE
                                             WHEN Qusetion_NO = 3
                                             THEN answer
                                         END)), '') AS [3],
       ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MAX(CASE
                                             WHEN Qusetion_NO = 4
                                             THEN answer
                                         END)), '') AS [4]
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY ID;
```

**Desired Output :**

```
ID     1    2    3   4
001    a    b        c
002    d    e    f   g
```